# In Python given a singly linkedlist, fold it by splitting it in half (around median) and reverse each half

Tags: python, reverse

I could reverse it but got confused on how to accesss median of linkedlist

```
def reverseLinkedList(head):

    current =  head
    previous = None
    nextNode = None

    while current:
        nextNode = current.nextNode
        current.nextNode = previous

        previous = current
        current = nextNode

    return previous
```

Can someone help with solution?

Comment: Do you have constraints on time/space complexity?

Comment: I instinctively feel this is best accomplished by converting to array, doing the reversals there, and converting back to linkedlist.

Answer (score 0):

Linked lists don't support random access. So unless you know ahead of time the number of elements in a linked list or the middle node is marked as such by virtue of the node structure/definition in your code then you won't be able to get it without iterating.

If you know the number of elements in the linked list you can just iterate half of them, otherwise you'll have to iterate the full list, keep track of a count, and then iterate again to count divided by two.